# How to prevent time delay/racing in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, pyautogui

I'm trying to implement a script which will play the game snake using the a* algorithm. The game was given to me by someone else (my teacher) and I have to write an working script that plays the game as good as possible, using this exact algorithm or some variation of it.

Now, I have written the algorithm and tried various simulations of it and it turns out that it works just fine, however since the game is an .exe I have to take a screenshot of the game screen and transform that into input data for my algorithm from that I construct a path and give commands to the snake using `pyautogui`.

So to summarize, the algorithm:

1. Take screenshot
2. Calculate path and moves
3. Move towards goal
4. Repeat until snake dies or certain score is reached.

The problem which I face is that the snake has a certain time which it takes to make 1 move and I delay the key press accordingly to that time, however when I reach the goal I have to repeat all the steps and steps `1-2` always take about `45-55ms` to complete and in that time my snake will end up dying because it didn't react quick enough. So what would be a good way to prevent this?

The solution I came up with, works sometimes, but a time delay will form and the snake will either make one move too early or too late at some point which might be deadly:

```
def simulate_movement(moves, speed):

for move in moves:
    text, pause = move
    interval1 = round(pause * speed, 1)
    if move == moves[-1]:
        interval1 = 0.05  # I speed up the final move because steps 1 and 2 take about 0.05ms
    pyautogui.press(text, interval=interval1)
```

Example of what the delay might cause:

[image]

The snake in the image has died, however the path which was correct was provided for it, but because it didn't react in time (because of mentioned delay) it bumped into the corner. Is there a way to for example make some code block which takes between `50-60ms` to make it run `100ms` so that is do nothing until that time passes, because that way I could get rid of the delay by subtracting `100ms` from the final move and waiting `100ms` until next moves are calculated.

Comment: Yes, there is a `time.sleep()` method that you can use as a delay.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
It's difficult to find a solution when we can't trace the origin of the problem.

Comment: @Prune the code is rather long, should I write everything down in the question or maybe use something like pastebin?

Comment: Minimal, complete, verifiable example ...